# Convert overlapping datetime ranges into non-overlapping ranges with priorities

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, interval

I have data stored in a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Records
(
  [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) not null
  ,[From] datetime not null
  ,[To] datetime not null
  ,[Priority] int not null
)
```

Every row contains time record with from-to range and its priority.

I have following data:

| Id | From | To | Priority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-04T00:00:00Z | 2021-01-04T23:59:59Z | 0 |
| 2 | 2021-01-04T08:00:00Z | 2021-01-04T16:30:00Z | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-01-05T00:00:00Z | 2021-01-05T23:59:59Z | 0 |
| 4 | 2021-01-05T08:00:00Z | 2021-01-05T16:30:00Z | 1 |
| 5 | 2021-01-05T16:30:00Z | 2021-01-05T17:30:00Z | 100 |
| 6 | 2021-01-05T17:30:00Z | 2021-01-05T23:00:00Z | 100 |
| 7 | 2021-01-05T23:00:00Z | 2021-01-05T23:59:59Z | 100 |
| 8 | 2021-01-06T00:00:00Z | 2021-01-06T23:59:59Z | 0 |
| 9 | 2021-01-06T08:00:00Z | 2021-01-06T10:00:00Z | 100 |
| 10 | 2021-01-06T08:00:00Z | 2021-01-06T16:30:00Z | 1 |
| 11 | 2021-01-06T10:00:00Z | 2021-01-06T12:30:00Z | 100 |
| 12 | 2021-01-06T12:30:00Z | 2021-01-06T14:30:00Z | 100 |
| 13 | 2021-01-06T14:30:00Z | 2021-01-06T15:30:00Z | 100 |
| 14 | 2021-01-06T17:00:00Z | 2021-01-06T17:45:00Z | 100 |
| 15 | 2021-01-06T17:45:00Z | 2021-01-06T19:45:00Z | 100 |
| 16 | 2021-01-06T19:45:00Z | 2021-01-06T20:30:00Z | 100 |
| 17 | 2021-01-07T00:00:00Z | 2021-01-07T23:59:59Z | 0 |
| 18 | 2021-01-07T08:00:00Z | 2021-01-07T16:30:00Z | 1 |
| 19 | 2021-01-07T08:30:00Z | 2021-01-07T11:30:00Z | 100 |
| 20 | 2021-01-07T11:30:00Z | 2021-01-07T12:30:00Z | 100 |
| 21 | 2021-01-07T12:30:00Z | 2021-01-07T15:30:00Z | 100 |

It can be seen that there are records where from-to overlaps with other records. Records with bigger priority should overwrite records with smaller one.

Expected results should be:

| Id | From | To | Priority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-04T00:00:00Z | 2021-01-04T08:00:00Z | 0 |
| 2 | 2021-01-04T08:00:00Z | 2021-01-04T16:30:00Z | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-04T16:30:00Z | 2021-01-04T23:59:59Z | 0 |
| 3 | 2021-01-05T00:00:00Z | 2021-01-05T08:00:00Z | 0 |
| 4 | 2021-01-05T08:00:00Z | 2021-01-05T16:30:00Z | 1 |
| 5 | 2021-01-05T16:30:00Z | 2021-01-05T17:30:00Z | 100 |
| 6 | 2021-01-05T17:30:00Z | 2021-01-05T23:00:00Z | 100 |
| 7 | 2021-01-05T23:00:00Z | 2021-01-05T23:59:59Z | 100 |
| 8 | 2021-01-06T00:00:00Z | 2021-01-06T08:00:00Z | 0 |
| 9 | 2021-01-06T08:00:00Z | 2021-01-06T10:00:00Z | 100 |
| 11 | 2021-01-06T10:00:00Z | 2021-01-06T12:30:00Z | 100 |
| 12 | 2021-01-06T12:30:00Z | 2021-01-06T14:30:00Z | 100 |
| 13 | 2021-01-06T14:30:00Z | 2021-01-06T15:30:00Z | 100 |
| 10 | 2021-01-06T15:30:00Z | 2021-01-06T16:30:00Z | 1 |
| 8 | 2021-01-06T16:30:00Z | 2021-01-06T17:00:00Z | 0 |
| 14 | 2021-01-06T17:00:00Z | 2021-01-06T17:45:00Z | 100 |
| 15 | 2021-01-06T17:45:00Z | 2021-01-06T19:45:00Z | 100 |
| 16 | 2021-01-06T19:45:00Z | 2021-01-06T20:30:00Z | 100 |
| 8 | 2021-01-06T20:30:00Z | 2021-01-06T23:59:59Z | 0 |
| 17 | 2021-01-07T00:00:00Z | 2021-01-07T08:00:00Z | 0 |
| 18 | 2021-01-07T08:00:00Z | 2021-01-07T08:30:00Z | 1 |
| 19 | 2021-01-07T08:30:00Z | 2021-01-07T11:30:00Z | 100 |
| 20 | 2021-01-07T11:30:00Z | 2021-01-07T12:30:00Z | 100 |
| 21 | 2021-01-07T12:30:00Z | 2021-01-07T15:30:00Z | 100 |
| 18 | 2021-01-07T15:30:00Z | 2021-01-07T16:30:00Z | 1 |
| 17 | 2021-01-07T16:30:00Z | 2021-01-07T23:59:59Z | 0 |

Possible way how to solve it I have found on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/SQL/comments/6gsoj7/prioritising_overlapping_time_ranges_to_produce_a/ditsyfe), but it does not work on my dataset as you can see on [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e7a1f/7) (with small change - on reddit lower priority beats higher priority, I need: higher priority beats lower priority).

Basically:

```
0:      ++++++++++++++++++++++++
1:              ----------       
100:                  |||||||
result: ++++++++------|||||||+++
```

Any suggestion/solution on how to solve it on SQL Server 2012?

I thought that it is common problem, however I was not able to find a solution on the internet yet.

---

Just to clarify my problem, I have overlapping events like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| #ID:1#                       00:00-23:59                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+

                     +-----------------------------+
                     | #ID:2#  08:00-16:30         |
                     +-----------------------------+
```

I need to get this (because ID2 has higher priority than ID1):

```
+--------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+
| #ID:1# 00:00-08:00 | #ID:2# 08:00-16:30          | #ID:1# 16:30-23:59 |
+--------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+
```

If ID2 had lower priority than ID1, it would be like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| #ID:1#                       00:00-23:59                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

There can be many events in the same time with different priorities.

Answer (score 1):

We can formulate your query in the following way:

- We want all time intervals, for which there are no other time intervals that overlap AND also have a higher priority.
- We can define overlapping as: the start time of one interval is between the start and end time of another.
- Assuming here that two intervals starting and finishing coterminus are NOT overlapping. This means we don't consider two intervals with one having *To* the same as the other *From* as being overlapping, they are just abutting each other.
- This is somewhat complicated by the fact that you appear to want the ID of the original record, so we cannot just filter out unnecessary records with `WHERE`

```
SELECT
    ID,
    [From] = ISNULL(priority.[From], r.[From]),
    [To] = ISNULL(priority.[To], r.[To])
FROM Records r
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM Records priority
    WHERE priority.[From] >= r.[From]
        AND priority.[From] < r.[To]    -- Change to <= for coterminus
        AND priority.ID <> r.ID
    ORDER BY priority.Priority DESC
) priority
```

I would advise you to have an index with `From` as the leading column, and including `To`, `Priority` and `ID`.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your description and example, i think what you are looking for is this:

```
;with prep as (
select distinct [From] as timeValue from Records
union
select distinct  [To] from Records)
,intervals as (
select prep.timeValue as newFrom, lead(prep.timeValue) over (order by timeValue asc) as newTill
  from prep )
  select * 
  from intervals as intervals
  cross apply (select coalesce(max(priority),0) as  val
               from Records
               where Records.[From] = intervals.newFrom) as priority
where datediff(day,newFrom,newTill)=0
```

This splits overlapping time intervals, they dont cross dates (thats the way i understand the requirements) and gives priority based on their source.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it does not work. Yes, input data does not cross dates. Your solution seems to fail when multiple events overlaps. It produces this row:
`2021-01-06 15:30:00.000 2021-01-06 16:30:00.000 0` but it should be `2021-01-06 15:30:00.000 2021-01-06 16:30:00.000 1` And column with ID is missing